# Haskell Curry Function and Brackets

Tags: function, haskell, currying

Hi this is probably a very simple problem but I'm having issue with it. I'm trying to make a roots function with the formula:

```
 roots a b c = ((-b + t)/a', (-b - t)/a')
 where
 t  = b ^ 2 - 4 * a * c
 a' = 2 * a
```

I'm now trying to make it a curried function however I can't seem to get it to work this is what I've put:

```
roots:: Double -> (Double -> (Double -> Double))
```

Could someone please help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Your function is already curried: `roots:: Double -> Double -> Double -> (Double, Double)`

Comment: By the way, the indentions in your code are wrong. `where` should have more indention, and `t` and `a'` should have the same indentions that are larger than `where`'s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Haskell, functions are automatically curried. So you don't have to do anything special to make them curried.

Your function roots is of the type `roots:: Double -> Double -> Double -> (Double, Double)`. Something like this will typecheck: `let a = roots 3.0` because of currying.

In case your `roots` function was not curried, then it is likely to have a type like this: `roots:: (Double , Double , Double) -> (Double, Double)` which is not the proper way to write function definitons.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know (but I'm not the expert, just had couple of lessons 'bout Haskell so far) function that gets 3 input parameters and produces one output (like in your example) should be written like:

```
roots:: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
```

Last element in the chain (forth Double) is return type, all previous ones are input parameter types.
This should do the trick

Comment: No that doesn't work, also you need the brackets in there to tell that your going into a different function. SORRY WAS WRONG! You don't have to have the brackets!